# How to make CSS Grid fit to screen size?

Tags: html, grid

I am using CSS Grid for my website. I would like to know how to make wrapper (divs) fit the screen size?

Comment: which grid are you using ? your own ? chat does the code looks like ? are you using float ? inline ? tell us more

Comment: CSS grid, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
I am not using float.

Comment: It seems to be in your ".container" declaration, with the "grid-template-columns" property. Have you try to change those values ??

Comment: I fixed my problem. I would like to ask how to add rows into a column?

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the wrapper (divs) to be 100%.

Comment: works, but why we need to put the grid in a container ? Can you tell us more about the principles behind the scene please ?